# NodeJS, Mongoose - Query city, state, or zip

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a MongoDB database that has a list of cities, states, and zip codes.  I would like to be able to run a query that will check each of these fields depending on a user input and am having trouble figuring out how to go about doing this.  Here is an example of document in the db:

```
{"_id":"92199","city":"San Diego","state":"CA"}
```

Here is my route I'm using to return that document:

```
    app.get('/city/:city', function(req, res){
        var query = City.aggregate( [
           { $group: { _id: "$zip", city: {"$first" : "$city"}, state: {"$first" : "$state"} } },
           { $match: {"city": new RegExp(req.params.city, "i")} }
        ]);
        query.exec(function(err, city){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return res.send(err);
            }
            console.log(city);
            res.json(city);
        });
    });
```

The problem is that if I some queries San Diego, CA the query will fail because it's only searching the city. How would query the city, the state, and zip (_id) so that a value will still be returned?

Comment: shouldn't aggregation done once and not per request

Comment: I just used aggregation because all of my searches seemed to point to it as the way you query multiple fields.

Comment: This sounds like a normal query (not something that needs aggregation) -- what do you mean about "the query will fail because it's only searching the city"?

Comment: (That is to say, you can just perform a find() where your query object has one or more of _id, city, and state properties in any combination and it will return all matching docs. But perhaps I'm missing some aspect of what you wish to achieve.)

Comment: The way the query currently works is that it's just searching the city field so if I search for "San Diego, CA" it will fail because it is not searching for the state and no city field contains "San Diego, CA", just "San Diego.

Comment: I think you're right through, I will just do it the way you mentioned, I don't know why I didn't think of that before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up working out for me in case anyone is interested.  Probably going to refactor but this works:

```
    app.get('/city/:city', function(req, res){

        var location = req.params.city.replace(",", "");
        location = toTitleCase(location);
        location = location.split(" ");

        for (var i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
            if(location[i].length == 2){
                var state = location[i].toUpperCase();
                var stateIndex = i;
            }
            if(!isNaN(parseFloat(location[i])) && isFinite(location[i])){
                var zip = location[i];
                var zipIndex = i;
            }               
        }

        if(zipIndex){
            location.splice(zipIndex, 1);
        }
        if(stateIndex){
            location.splice(stateIndex, 1);
        }

        location = location.join(" ");

        if(state && zip){
             var query = City.find({
            $and: [
                { $and: [{"state": state}, {"city": new RegExp(location, "i")}] },
                { "zip" : zip }
            ]
        });
        }else if(zip){
            var query = City.find({
                $or : [{"city": new RegExp(location, "i")}, {"zip" : zip}]
            });
        }else if(state){
            var query = City.find({
                 $and: [{"state": state}, {"city": new RegExp(location, "i")}]
            });
        }
        else{
             var query = City.find({
                "city": new RegExp(location, "i")
            });
        }
        query.exec(function(err, city){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(city);
        });
    });
```

Credit goes to @Semicolon for his help in comments.